# Is Circle mask image Plugin broken?

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

in Phaser,I load the plugin in preload function

```
    class Main extends Phaser.Scene {
    
        constructor() {
            super("Main");
        }
    
       preload() {
         this.load.plugin('rexcirclemaskimageplugin', 
           'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex- 
            notes/master/dist/rexcirclemaskimageplugin.min.js', true)
        
          this.load.image('image', 
           'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex- 
            notes/master/assets/images/rectangle128x96.jpg');
        }
  // create function here
   }
```

inside the Create function when I use the plugin

```
create() {
    this.add.image(200, 500, 'image').setOrigin(0);
  
    this.add.rexCircleMaskImage(300, 200, 'image', {
        maskType: 'ellipse'
    });
}
```

gives me an error => this.add.rexCircleMaskImage is not a function,
it means that the rexCircleMaskImage plugin has not been loaded correctly or what?

I would greatly appreciate any help
thank you

[image]

Comment: Does my answer help with your problem? If not can you share some more code, without seeing how / where the call is made. further debugging is not easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin in works checkout [this example linked](https://codepen.io/rexrainbow/pen/XWrMKBY) from the plugin docs ([link to the plugin documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/circlemaskimage/)).

The question is, where are you calling the line `let mask = this.add.rexCircleMaskImage(0, 0, key, {maskType: 2, radius: radius})`, this error sounds like a wrong *context/scope* error. The `this` should refer to the a `Phaser.Scene`, the previous line should be called inside a Scene methode.

**Update *(from comments)*:**

The problem hast to do with the phaser Version, the plugin needs atleast version 3.6.0.

> *"...Please upgrade your phaser3 to version >= 3.60.0. ..."
>
> ([Quote from k from the plugin page](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/plugin-list/))*

Comment: thanks for replying,  I use it in the main Scene, inside function that I call it in Create Function and when I log "this" it gives me this main Scene, and I noticed in the object there is the only plugin that it works fine but the rexcirclemaskimageplugin doesn't exist  https://prnt.sc/mRliXTEwLa1Z

Comment: I have some questions, can you add the `create` function into your question, so that I can see how the code looks like? I just need to see how the code is nested.  btw. does the Main class extends `Phaser.Scene`? **btw:** the plugin exists, if it is in the array it exisits (`data: null` is just a property from the plugin, that is `null`). And last but not least which phaser version are you using Phaser v3.60.0 , or lower?

Comment: I edited my question by putting the example that you refer to previously instead of my code because it's a little bit messy and nested and the issue is still there.
 for Phaser version I use v3.55.2.....
thanks again

Comment: it works now when I update from Phaser v3.55.2 to v3.60.0
Yeeeees, thank you so much winner_joiner

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you could consider accepting my answer _(with the green checkmark)_, I added the information from the comments, to the answer.